# dynamic title not displaying correctly in WP

Tags: wordpress

I have trouble in my own WP theme. At the front page, I'm displaying 3 last articles. When the title is static (for ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet), the title correctly continue to next row if some word could overflow. But when dynamically outputting the title from db, the title just overflow the line width, not continuing on second row.

For displaying the title from db I use WP function the_title();.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be happening because the titles you're retrieving from the database have varying lengths and font sizes, which may cause some titles to overflow the line width and not continue on a second row.

To fix this, you can try adding the following CSS styles to your WordPress theme:

```
.title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

This will cause any title that exceeds two lines to be truncated with an ellipsis ("...") and not overflow the line width.

You can also adjust the -webkit-line-clamp value to specify how many lines of text you want to display before truncating the title.

Comment: It doesn't really help. What works is not copy from gmail view for docs. But from words, pdf, ppt etc. Good enough for now.